# Similar adjectives for "misfit"

Tags: word-choice

I am looking for cool one-word adjectives for a character in my story who is the "odd-one-out", "misfit", even a smart weirdo in some ways who is unable to pair with others due to divergent way of thinking.

Comment: Parvin, your question, without context and a sample sentence, is going to lead to a list of opinions, most of which will not be appropriate to that intended context.

Answer (score 1):

Nouns: outlier, nonconformist, eccentric

Adjectives: eccentric, free-thinking, unconventional, independent, iconcoclastic (maybe a bit too spicy for what you're going for)